# How to split single column (with unequal values) to multiple columns sorted according to values from the original single column?

Tags: vba, excel

How do I separate values from single columns to multiple columns with the new columns sorted by values (and sometimes blank cells) using Excel Macro code?

[image]

Comment: Did you need to use VBA? This could easily be achievable using a formula.

Comment: You could use a formula like `=IF(IFERROR(FIND($2:$2,$A:$A),0)>0,$2:$2,"")` in cells `B3:F7`

Comment: I'm still quite new to Excel. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try: `=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B$1,$A2)),B$1,"")`

[image]

Comment: You're welcome, please don't forget mark my answer as the answer in your post I am building my reputation :)