# Split a delimited list based on variable ending characters into specific columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have managed to get to a point with a data set where i have a list of items delimited with a "|" symbol. I am now trying to separate each item in the list into the corresponding column, however the identifier of the column is a bit of text at the end of each value of variable length.

Example Data (all in one column):

```
Column A   
40.00A|24.00QS|8.00J[a]
40.00A|12.00J|8.00J[a]
20.00A|4.00V
30.00A|12.00CS|8.00QS
```

Desired Outcome:

---

```
+-------+-------+------+-------+-------+------+
|   A   |  QS   | J[a] |   J   |  CS   |  V   |
+-------+-------+------+-------+-------+------+
| 40.00 | 23.00 | 8.00 |       |       |      |
| 40.00 |       | 8.00 | 12.00 |       |      |
| 20.00 |       |      |       |       | 4.00 |
| 30.00 |  8.00 |      |       | 12.00 |      |
+-------+-------+------+-------+-------+------+
```

The number of trailing characters that define columns is fixed to 6 (A,QS,J[a],J,CS & V), so I know at the beginning how many columns I will need.

I have some ideas on how to do it directly through formulas, but it would require me to split out the items into individual columns by the delimiter, then use some sort of if statement on some additional columns. Would prefer to avoid the helper column issue. Also, looked at the following link, but it doesn't solve the solution, as it assumes the value matches the column heading (I can correct that, but I feel like there is a faster VBA solution here):
[How to split single column (with unequal values) to multiple columns sorted according to values from the original single column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48260670/how-to-split-single-column-with-unequal-values-to-multiple-columns-sorted-acco)

I have been reading about Regular Expressions, and i suspect there is a solution there, but I can't quite figure out how to sort the result.

Once i have this data setup, it is a small task to unpivot it and get the data in a proper tabular format using Power Query.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do the order of the columns matter?

Comment: This is not a code writting service.  If you have already wrote some code than share it with us and we will help you to improve it but don't expect anyone to do your job for you.

Comment: @Skin, the order doesn't matter.

Comment: I didn't include the other code as it really wasn't relevant and includes some confidential items. The solution that preceded my question was using VBScript.RegExp and a pattern to insert the "|" into the data source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since headers are fixed, it can simply be tried out like this (the Row & Column of the Source & destination data may be changed to your requirement)

[image]

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()
Dim Ws As Worksheet, SrcLastrow As Long, TrgRow As Long, Rw As Long
Dim Headers As Variant, xLine As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
'Column A assumed to have the texts
SrcLastrow = Ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
TrgRow = 2
Headers = Array("A", "QS", "J[a]", "J", "CS", "V")

For Rw = 1 To SrcLastrow
xLine = Split(Ws.Cells(Rw, 1).Value, "|")
    For i = 0 To UBound(xLine)
    For j = 0 To UBound(Headers)
    xLine(i) = Trim(xLine(i))
        If Right(xLine(i), Len(Headers(j))) = Headers(j) Then
        Ws.Range("D" & TrgRow).Offset(0, j).Value = Replace(xLine(i), Headers(j), "") ' The output data table was assumed to be at Column D 
        End If
    Next j
    Next i
TrgRow = TrgRow + 1
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @Ahmed-AU! That totally helps! I was trying to come up with a solution that looped through each of the column table names on each line, and using a "Mid" to try and figure out where it was and where it ended, and was having a tough time getting started on the problem.